# Different versions of Google Play services cannot be declared depending on the device configuration

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-app-bundle

When trying to upload my application (aab) to the play store - Im seeing this error, and I cant find ***anyone*** talking about it. The error message is translated from Swedish -> English using Google Translate.

The versions used are 0, and 12451000. Its clear to me that the 0 is a mistake, but Ive now spent several days trying to figure out where the 0 is coming from without any success.

**Things Ive tried;**

- Export the aab using different versions of Android Studio. Ive tried stable, beta & canary.
- Reduce versions of my dependencies to the ones I know have worked in the past.
- Update dependencies, gradle, libraries, etc.
- Invalidate caches, reinstall Android Studio, wipe its settings and follow its 'repair IDE' wizard.
- Verify that build.gradle and plugins are written & used correctly.

My usage of the play services is quite broad, I apply them in my app/phone module with an additional line in my plugins block `id 'com.google.gms.google-services'`. The root build.gradle contains the classpath to `com.google.gms:google-services`.

My full related dependencies are as follows (declared in TOML);

```
firebase-gradle = { module = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle', version = '2.8.1' }
firebase-bom = { module = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-bom', version = '29.3.0' }
firebase-crashlytics = { module = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx' }
firebase-auth = { module = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx' }
firebase-database = { module = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx' }

google-gradle = { module = 'com.google.gms:google-services', version.ref = 'google-services' }
google-auth = { module = 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth', version.ref = 'google-auth' }
google-fitness = { module = 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness', version.ref = 'google-fitness' }

google-services = '4.3.10'
google-auth = '20.1.0'
google-fitness = '21.0.1'
```

At this point Im looking for any guidance I can get. Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I can take? Have you experienced something similar in the past? Please let me know.

Comment: Have a look at the merged manifest in the intermediate build files of Studio. Then look for the lines that declare the version of Google play services, and when you see the one with 0, it will show if it's defined in your own manifest or if it comes from a library you depend on.

Comment: @Pierre Theres just one entry with it, and its pointing towards @integer/google_play_services_version which seems to be the correct value.

Comment: Do you have multiple dynamic modules in your app? Can you try running `java -jar bundletool.jar dump manifest --bundle=/path/to/app.aab` and check the manifest there? You can download bundletool from its GitHub repo.

Comment: @Pierre I dont use dynamic modules. I just ran the bundletool, the manifest looks pretty much identical to what Im seeing in Android Studio - namely the play services version points to the exact same resource. Is there anything in particular I should look at other than that?

Comment: Running out of ideas. You might need to talk to the developer support if that still doesn't work.

Comment: Ill do that and report back!

Comment: @zoltish try to set version without using res integer but a hardcode directly in the manifest - sometimes this helps.

Comment: @PavloOstasha I just tried this - no difference unfortunately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a versioning problem. Try changing the

```
com.android.application and com.android.library
```

versions from `7.3.0-alpha 07` to `7.1.2.`

Alternatively, try the remedy below

```
androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().all(), {
        def capitalizedVariantName = name.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1)
afterEvaluate {

tasks.named("map${capitalizedVariantName}SourceSetPaths").configure {
    it.dependsOn("process${capitalizedVariantName}GoogleServices")
  }
}
```

})
}

The issue has been fixed and closed. Check it here on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/223240936)
The work around could be unnecessary.

Comment: New hope! Unfortunately it it did not make any difference for me :(

Comment: There was indeed a bug in Play Console with apps built with 7.3.0-alphaXX. The bug has now been fixed.

Comment: Yea true it has been fixed https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/223240936

Comment: And it finally works! :) Thank you all for responding!